# can the backdrop app be styled, customized or replaced?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

On Chromecast, is there any way to customize, style (with CSS), or replace the backdrop application?

(That's the application that runs as a sort of screen saver, when nothing's being cast to the device).

My ideal backdrop app would be an iframe showing something I could control.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be styled or replaced. You have some level of control on what images or information show up there (can be set in your Chromecast app); that is all.